# how to switch to the other git account in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea 15.
I commit code to github with account A before，
And I want use account B commit code to github now.
How to switch to the other account?

Comment: Multiple Github account management for a single project will require you to perform `git` commands via command line/terminal. IntelliJ doesn't support multiple Github accounts for 1 instance of IntelliJ. If you want to do it through IntelliJ, you'll need to completely change to a different account in `Settings > Version Control > Github`

Comment: No, This issue related to Intellij idea, Actually I done some change in command line. Intellij idea still use the old account.

Comment: As I said, IntelliJ doesn't support multiple account management, you'll have to login to a different account through `Settings > Version Control > Github` to change to a different Github account. I was implying that you perform your `git commit`s and `git push`es via command line whilst managing multiple accounts on the same computer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to completely change the Github account credentials for IntelliJ.

1. Go into your Settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
2. Go to `Version Control > Github`
3. Edit your credentials.

---

As you noted in the comments to your question, you need to change the Author Name as well.

Comment: Thx, The author can be changed when do commit action.

Comment: This Method Successfully works on PyCharm IDE also!!